# Why has the rule squid:CycleBetweenPackages been removed from the Java "Sonar way with Findbugs" quality profile?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have just updated SonarQube from 5.3 to 5.6.3 
Running a first analysis I realized that the rule squid:CycleBetweenPackages has been removed from the "Sonar way with Findbugs" Java quality profile.

Is there a specific reason this rule has been removed from the default profile? If I add it manually to the quality profile, it is ignored and not added to the ruleset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is indeed a pretty good reason, this rule was dropped in version 4.0 of the java plugin as mentioned by this ticket : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1717

Main reason to remove that rule is that it is out of scope of the core feature SonarQube Analyzers aim to provide.

Comment: Is there a way to bring a similar functionality back? I find it quite useful

Comment: I invite you to make this feedback on our community forum : https://discuss.sonarsource.com/